# Forge.ui.enhanceInput - change event not fired on input

Tags: android, android-webview, trigger.io

I'm using `Forge.ui.enhanceInput` to show a native time picker for `<input type="time">` on Android.

The problem is when the forge native time picker returns, no change event is fired on the input. There are no callbacks available on on Forge.ui.enhanceInput either, so currently I do not know how to find out when the date has been entered.

Are there any solutions for this, so I can know when a date has been entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for the 'blur' event on the input element. Since our v1.4.23 release the native picker fires that event when complete:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-23

Comment: Thanks Amir. Should have updated this Q earlier - we did some more experimentation and found that blur would do the trick.